# How to prove this existence and uniqueness?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove existence and uniqueness of two factors for matrix operations but I don't know at all what I should do, here is the exercise:

$$
R(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I have already proved that $R(\theta)^n=R(n\theta)$.
Now I need to prove that

> For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $b\ne0$ and
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$$
>   there exist only one $\lambda>0$ and only one $\theta\in\mathopen{]}0,2\pi\mathclose{[}$ such that
>   $$ A=\lambda R(\theta).$$

How can I prove it?

Comment: FYI, *uniqueness, not unicity

Comment: @parsiad Thanks I corrected it!

Comment: @parsiad that's a cursive n

Comment: Hint: matrices of this form are isomorphic to complex numbers.

Comment: @parsaid in fact, it seems that [both are technically correct](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/225098/46438) (or at least, both are in the OED). However, "uniqueness" is much more common among native English speakers and is more likely to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda$ and $\theta$ exist. Then $A=\lambda R(\theta)$, so $\det A=\det(\lambda R(\theta))$ and so
$$
a^2+b^2=\lambda^2
$$
Thus $\lambda=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Now your task is to see that there exists a unique $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$ with
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\qquad\sin\theta=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$
Hint: The point with coordinates $\biggl(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\biggr)$ belongs to the circle with radius $1$ and center the origin.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I can't understand why lambda² = a² + b² ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise calculate the determinant of each of $A$ and $\lambda R(\theta)$

Comment: @John11 oh thank you, I understand for this part now but I can't understand the rest, I have difficulties to see how proving that will prove the original problem ? I don't know how to prove it either 

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ specialist here. `;-)` I added a further hint.

Comment: Ah ah thank you !! I am working on it 

Comment: We can discard $\theta=\pi$ because $b=\lambda \sin \pi=0$.

Comment: Since it's on that circle and that we are using sin and cos and cos and thêta is between 0 and 2Pi, I do understand that once we will have proven that it exists, it will be unique, but Don't know how to prove that I exists or why we are trying to prove that in the first place...

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Connect the point on the circle with the origin: $\theta$ is the angle between this line and the positive $x$-semiaxis. Definition of cosine and sine.

Comment: @egreg I am starting to understand it a little bit better, especially why we are proving it this way (as always it looks soo obvious once I realize it…), so actually, now that we have proven that lambda is equal to sqrt(a² + b²) we only care about proving the existence and uniqueness of thêta right ?

Comment: Oh wait, belong to circle means that it is on the "circle line" and not inside of the circle right ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Right so!

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise You might be interested in knowing that this is basically the expression of a complex number in trigonometric form. `;-)`